# Pure html uploader

Tags: php, javascript, html, uploader

is there any script in html to upload files 
it should be only 1 html file (can include js , etc) but should be 1 file .html
NO php
and the path where the file is uploaded (if possible)

Comment: No, there isn't. HTML forms need a POST receiver, you cannot initiate a script-free upload so; that would require a PUT request.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any script in html to upload files it should be only 1 html file (can include js , etc) but should be 1 file .html NO php and the path where the file is uploaded (if possible)

Well your requirement states that you need a 'Pure HTML (and JS)' web page on the client side that will handle the file upload.

Now there are two parts to this..

**On the Client side:**

1. We need HTML tags like `<input type="file" ... />` embedded in a
   `<form>` tag to capture the file to be uploaded.

   2.a. How do you want to send the file..? Should it be when the users submits the page then all you need to do is have the action
   attribute of the `<form>` point to the PHP page sitting on the server
   to accept the data been sent across.

   2.b. Maybe you want to send the file asynchronously (in the background). Well in this case you could use several JQuery AJAX
   File uploader plugins to do this for you. Google could turn up quite
   a few results.

   > Note that on HTML4 browsers the ONLY way you can send a file to the
   >   server is when a form is submitted - so technically a one page AJAX
   >   isn't possible here. But the illusion of a async file upload is
   >   created by using a hidden iframe to do the upload. Luckily we have
   >   great plugins that make it easy like Plupload and Uploadify, the later
   >   which I have used once.  Note that these plugins also allow you to use
   >   Flash/Silverlight uploaders which is not in your requirements.
   >   Needless to say, Silverlight/Flash allow for a async file upload.

   2.c. HTML5 async file upload: Basically HTML5 replaces Flash/Silverlight by caching the file in memory and then we use JQuery to send it across using AJAX..

   I found this tut a few months ago that explains this well :) :
   http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/

**Finally on the Server side:**

1. Here you would have a  basic PHP script that will read the binary data of the file from the variable `$_FILES['<name of input file tag in the form>']`

Hope this helps! Hey do let me know how you finally decide to proceed with this.

All the best!

Comment: i cant use php there dude :\ ......
i only can edit the html file ....
so is there any way to upload or include a php file???
can we include the php file from another server using html .....
so that i can work on that server and can upload the php later onn

Comment: Oh ok.. Seems like you don't have rights to upload PHP code onto the server but can host HTML files there.. Is this the case?

Comment: @user1708712 dude I guess you need to check wit ur hosting provider as they might have some pre-installed PHP plugins for this. As I have explained above, there is NO other way around this.. probably they don't want users to upload anything.. check their Terms of Service doc..

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need a server-side application process it (PHP, ASP.NET, a CGI executable, etc).  Sorry

Comment: i heard that it is possible in html5

Comment: You can't put a file on a server without a server app.  You may be thinking of HTML5's ability to store data on the client.

Comment: Html5 gears and Javascript fileApi will help you doing it without page load, but you still need a server end language to save it to the server. There is no way that html or js can save a file to a server

Comment: isn't there any default file in server that we can use??

Comment: what's the problem using a server end language like php or python